# Select2 control in dijit dialog - unable to focus

Tags: dojo, xpages, jquery-select2

Since Domino 9.01FP2 you can no longer focus on a Select2 control within a xe:dialog.
It appears to be caused by a change in dojo version as it worked prior to FP2.

I understand the root cause is with the dijit dialog's layout manager (or underlay) preventing focus on things outside of the modal, and the select2 dropdown is appended at the end of the page.

There's documented fixes for this when using it with a jquery modal e.g.

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};

but I can't find any equivalent fix for dojo i.e. to register the select2 dropdown as something which is allowed to have focus.

NB: I think this 'fix' in dojo may have caused the issue
https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15370

a potential solution I thought of is to use the select2's open event to move it to be within the dialog but I had no luck with that.

Is anyone using select2 with dojo or is that just a weird use case as most people would use jquery? (outside of xpages)

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long time debugging Dojo I managed to get this to work.
As a fudge you can put this into your xe:dialog code

```
<xe:this.onShow><![CDATA[//fudge to make select2 work
dijit.byId('#{id:myDialog}')._fadeOutDeferred = true; ]]></xe:this.onShow>
```

Dojo allows nodes to get focus if:

1. They are a child of the dialog
2. They have a class of digitPopup
3. the _fadeOutDeferred property is set to true

This has aside effect of making the dialog modeless as you can click on anything outside of the popup but at least the select2 controls work again :)

Comment: You saved my day :) I had the same issue, not sure what changed with the POODLE HF from IBM, but, my select2 field was not getting the focus. I've been trying to solve this issue last two weeks. Thanks.

Comment: THANKS!!! Just spent the last few days getting Select2 to work and then it died when I put it in a dialog, this saved me!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the property 'autofocus' of the dialog to false.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work as the issue is when you try and focus on the select2 control, not when the dialog first pops up